# Change the letter to the next element in the string in my HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, getelementbyid

I want to display one letter at a time on my homepage from a given string. 
The alert function iterates through the for loop no problem but the 'letter' on in my HTML skips to the end. Help !

```
<div class='message'> <p id='letter'>T</p>  </div>        

<script>
var str= "Thank you for finding me"

for ( i=0; i < str.length; i++){
   alert(str[i]);
   document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML=str[i];

}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want time to pass between setting the innerHTML each time? Assuming the errors Vohuman pointed out are not in your actual code (you said it worked, so they must not be). You included setInterval as a tag so you must realize the code above doesn't account for spacing the iterations over time...

Comment: Yeah I'm struggling to work out how to delay changing letter - as the for loop just skips to the end I want each character of the string displayed.

Answer (score 3):

There were a few syntax errors in your code, but to achieve the effect you're looking for you should take a different approach.

Even if your loop did function correctly, there is no delay between the iterations of the loop, so it will just *seem* to skip to the last letter.

I would use a recursive function to achieve this effect.

```js
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var cyclical = false; // Restart the loop once it has ended?

function say(string, index) {
  if(index < string.length) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      letter.innerHTML = string[index];
      say(string,++index);
    },500); // Milliseconds between iterations.
  } else if(cyclical) {
    say(string,0); // Restart the loop once it has ended
  }
}

say("Thank you for finding me",0);
```

```html
<div class='message' style="height: 1.5em;">
  <p id='letter'></p>
</div>
<!-- Demo purposes only -->
<label for="#cyclical"><input type="checkbox" id="cyclical" onclick="cyclical ? cyclical = false : cyclical = true">Cyclical</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches you could take. Forgetting older IE versions to keep the code clear, here's one:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('letter');
var str  = 'Thank you for finding me';
var int  = 500;
var past = 0;

for (var char of str) {
    setTimeout(function(char) {
        elem.innerHTML = char;
    }.bind(null, char)), past);

    past += int;
}
```

Note the use of bind to "lock in" the value of char. Without it (or another approach that achieves the same thing, a new var in a new scope), char would refer to "char" in the loop, which will already be at the end of iteration ('e') by the time it executed the deferred function.